# Set default value to mapped buttons with value from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, reactstrap

[image]

I am building a component that will map some buttons with values from SQL.
"fetchedService" is the get request from my API and the model looks something like this:

"ServiceID": "GUID",
"ArticleName": "MyArticle",
"PriceExclVAT": 699,
"Default": true,

Right now, the one with "default:true" in the database gets highlighted.
I am trying to make it so that when i click on something else it should highlight that option and ignore the one set to default in the database.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve exactly using buttons but can't you use Radio buttons for this? They will change on the front-end and only allow a single selection. I guess the problem is you have 2 conditions for setting active. Either it's equal to the service id or its the default. So I'm assuming your API always sets a default and a re-render might then make this one active all the time when it re-renders the page

Comment: I am using a form of bootstrap called reactstrap. it has a ButtonGroup with mapped buttons inside of it. 
I never ment to have the || e.default == true in the active property, but i just dont know what else to write here. If i take that part out, nothing gets set to active if i do not click it first.

the api only has one set to default at all times, and that value never changes.

Comment: Would the following work ? `active={props.service === e.serviceID || (!props.service && e.default == true)}`

Comment: Unfortunately not. In the case you wrote there was no default value selected and when i clicked one of the buttons all of the buttons highlighted

Comment: Whatabout changing the second condition bit to ((!props.service || props.service ==‘’) && e.default == true). What is props.service equal to on first run before a selection as that would help workout what the condition should be